# Finding age at time of registration using difftime?

Tags: r, lubridate

I am new to using both R and lubridate, and am attempting to find out the age of a set of students at the time of registration. I have the following dates for each student's date of birth.

```
students_bd <-  c("04/08/95", "02/23/95", "03/14/95", "12/11/95", "06/23/95", 
          "04/04/95", "08/24/95", "08/13/95", "09/20/95")
students_bd <- as.Date(students_bd, "%m /%d /%y")
```

Additionally, the date of registration is 08/04/2014.

> Reg <- "08 / 04 / 2014" 
>   Reg_Date <- as.Date(Reg, "%m /%d /%Y")

I attempted to use difftime to get the answer, but this only provided me with the difference in days, not the age of the students at the time of registration. Time differences in days

> [1] -7058 -7102 -7083 -6811 -6982 -7062 -6920 -6931 -6893

What would be the most efficient way to not only get the answer, but to also display the age in ymd format for each student?

Comment: can u accept the answer , if it was useful and close

Answer (score 3):

```
as.period(Reg_Date - students_bd, units = "year")

    [1] "19y 0m 118d 6H 0M 0S"  "19y 0m 162d 6H 0M 0S"  "19y 0m 143d 6H 0M 0S"  "18y 0m 236d 12H 0M 0S"
[5] "19y 0m 42d 6H 0M 0S"   "19y 0m 122d 6H 0M 0S"  "18y 0m 345d 12H 0M 0S" "18y 0m 356d 12H 0M 0S"
[9] "18y 0m 318d 12H 0M 0S"
```

Comment: Your second solution asserts that all students are 19, but they're not?? You could also use: `as.period(Reg_Date-students_bd)@year` to extract the `year` slot from the period object.